# grid-size from environment variable in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm following partition pattern for Spring Batch. Currently I'm using a fixed grid-size of 10. Here is the master job configuration:

```
<batch:step id="master">
      <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
         <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
      </batch:partition>
</batch:step>
```

Is this possible to assign the grid-size from jvm arguments or spring application.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your grid-size value to following and when starting application from command line, append `--grid.size=10` in your command.

```
<batch:step id="master">
      <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
         <batch:handler grid-size="${grid.size}" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
      </batch:partition>
</batch:step>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @mhshimul